# what if member of private github organization is removed?

Tags: github

What if member is removed from the private GitHub organization?

Member access to private repositories's under the organization is also removed or not?

Comment: "Use this tag for questions specific to problems with repositories hosted on GitHub, **features specific to GitHub**..." - to closevoters, seems on-topic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Github help:

> When you remove a collaborator from your project, they lose read/write access to your repository. If the repository is private and the person has created a fork, then that fork is also deleted.

However note the next one:

> While forks of private repositories are deleted when a collaborator is removed, the person will still retain any local clones of your repository.

See this for reference: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-collaborator-from-a-personal-repository/

Comment: This question is not related to **one repository** its on Organizational level.

If I have removed one member from the Organization level member list should that member removed from the repositories under that organization?

Comment: Yes, Repository access also gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just logical, imagine someone is not a member of your company but he is still abled to see your projects and documents.

Comment: Yes, agree it make sense